# Karma + Angular 4 errors

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to set up testing for my Angular 4.1.3 application.  I am trying to follow this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#1st-karma-test

The problem I am having is that if I try to bring any dependencies, I start getting:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import**

Here is my karma.conf.ts:

```js
// karma.conf.ts
module.exports = function (config) {
 config.set({
  basePath: '/app',
  frameworks: ['jasmine'],
  plugins: [
   require('karma-jasmine'),
   require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
   require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter')
  ],
  client: {
   clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
  },
  files: [
   { pattern: '/components/**/*.spec.ts', watched: true },
   { pattern: '/tests/*.spec.ts', watched: true }
  ],
  mime: {
   'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx']
  },
  coverageIstanbulReporter: {
   reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
   fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
  },
  angularCli: {
   environment: 'dev'
  },
  reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
   ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
   : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
  port: 9876,
  colors: true,
  logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
  autoWatch: true,
  browsers: ['Chrome'],
  singleRun: false
 });
};
```

and here is my test:

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DatePipe } from '../helpers/pipes/date.pipe';

describe('DatePipe: Pipe', () => {

 let pipe: DatePipe;

 beforeEach(() => {
  pipe = new DatePipe();
 });

 afterEach(() => {
  pipe = null;
 });

 //create the test data
 let d: Date = new Date(2017, 1, 1);
 let format: string = 'MM/DD/YYYY';

 it('convert the date into a formatted string', () => {
  expect(pipe.transform(d, format)).toBe('01/01/2017');
 });
});
```

I am probably missing some configuration setting, but I cannot figure out what.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I see angularCli options, are you using angular cli?

Comment: not really.  I copied this config file from the Karma's site.

Comment: I just commented out the AngularCLI options and tried again, but got the same error

Comment: you need a preProcessor  for ts files, take a look at this tutorial for a minimal karma config: https://medium.com/@laco0416/setting-up-angular-2-testing-environment-with-karma-and-webpack-e9b833befd99